# How to run multiple instances of service?

Tags: java, android

How to run multiple instances of an service? It is posibble in android?

- Service for account 1
- Service for account 2

Comment: create different services..

Comment: means start a different service for each account !

Comment: Did you even try googling first? Clearly not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run multiple instances of a service. Moreover, you do no need to -- have one service support multiple accounts. For example, if you are using the command pattern, sending work to the service via `startService()`, provide an extra that identifies the account the command pertains to.